# Exception in thread

Tags: java, awt

I am new to Java programming. I am facing this error, and not understanding how to resolve this. Any help would be appreciated.

```java
public class ThermostatView extends JFrame
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                try
                {
                    ThermostatView frame = new ThermostatView();

                    frame.setVisible(true);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Constructs a ThermostatView
     */
    public ThermostatView()
    {
        thermostatObj = new Thermostat();
        initComponents();
    }
}
```

And this is my other class:

```java
public class Thermostat extends ThermostatView
{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public void setActualTempFunc(String actualTemp)
    {
        if(actualTemp.length() != 0)//actualTemp != null && !actualTemp.isEmpty())
            lblActualTemp.setText(actualTemp);
        else
            lblActualTemp.setText("-");
    }
}
```

the error is:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
JFrame cannot be resolved to a type

at Thermostat.<init>(Thermostat.java:3)
at ThermostatView.<init>(ThermostatView.java:145)
at ThermostatView$1.run(ThermostatView.java:128)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Looks like its getting caught in recursion.
Any help ???

Comment: Nothing to do with recursion. Import `javax.swing.JFrame` in your code, where referenced.

Comment: @ashutosh Looks like some environment specific issue. Are you running the code from Eclipse IDE?

Comment: Yeah, when your IDE says "The project has compilation problems, proceed with launch?" or something like that, don't just click "Yes", actually fix those pesky red underlines.

Answer (score 0):

I can see a few errors with your code.

1. You need to ensure you have all the required packages imported (e.g. java.awt.* etc).
2. Where are you delcaring lblActualTemp and thermostatObj ? You need to explicity delcare their type.

Using an IDE (development software) such as Eclipse, IntelliJ or Netbeans etc. usually spot these errors before you compile.